# Combining LINQ statements for efficiency

Tags: c#, linq, performance, where-clause

regarding linq to objects, if i use a .Where(x => x....) and then straight afterwards use a .SkipWhile(x => x...) does this incur a performance penalty because i am going over the collection twice?

Should i find a way to put everything in the Where clause or in the SkipWhile clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Where and a SkipWhile doesn't result in "going over the collection twice."  LINQ to Objects works on a pull model.  When you enumerate the combined query, the SkipWhile will start asking its source for elements.  Its source is the Where, so this will cause the Where to start asking its source in turn for elements.  So the SkipWhile will see all elements that pass the Where clause, but it's getting them as it goes.  The upshot is that LINQ does a foreach over the original collection, returning only elements that pass both the Where and SkipWhile filters -- and this involves only a single pass over the collection.

There may be a trivial loss of efficiency because there are two iterators involved, but it is unlikely to be significant.  You should write the code to be clear (as you are doing at the moment), and if you suspect that the clear version is causing a performance issue, *measure to make sure*, and only then try combining the clauses.

Answer (score 7):

There will be a minor inefficiency due to chaining iterators together, but it really will be very minor. (In particular, although each matching item will be seen by both operators, they won't be buffered up or anything like that. LINQ to Object isn't going to create a new list of all matching items and *then* run `SkipWhile` over it.)

If this is *so* performance-critical, you'd probably get a very slight speed bump by not using LINQ in the first place. In every other case, write the simplest code first and only worry about micro-optimisations like this when you've *proved* it's a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

As with most things the answer is it depends on what you're doing.  If you have multiple where's the operate on the same object it's probably worth combining them with &&'s for example.

Most of the LINQ operators won't iterate over the entire collection per operator, they merely process one item and pass it onto the next operator.  There are exceptions to this such as Reverse and OrderBy, but generally if you were using Where and SkipWhile for example you would have a chain that would process one item at a time.  Now your first Where statement could obviously filter out some items, so SkipWhile wouldn't see an item until it passed through the preceding operator.

My personal preference is to keep operators separate for clarity and combine them only if performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You *aren't* going over the collection twice when you use `Where` and `SkipWhile`.

The `Where` method will stream its output to the `SkipWhile` method one item at a time, and likewise the `SkipWhile` method will stream its output to any subsequent method one item at a time.

(There will be a small overhead because the compiler generates separate iterator objects for each method behind the scenes. But if I was worried about the overhead of compiler-generated iterators then I probably wouldn't be using LINQ in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's (essentially) no performance penalty.  That's what lazy (deferred) execution is all about.